# Laravel Set Model Table Name With Todays Date

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model in my laravel appication which uses a table which is re-created each day with a new table name that includes todays date.

I am trying to set the `protected $table` property in the model to

```
protected $table = "probe_request_" . $this->getDate;
```

This is how I have defined the `getDate` function

```
private function getDate()
{
    return Carbon::now('Europe/London')->startOfDay()->format('d_m_Y');
}
```

I keep receiving the following error `"<strong>Zend compile error</strong>: Constant expression contains invalid operations in <strong>/var/www/intelli_sense/app/sprinkles/geo-sense/src/Database/Models/ProbeRequest.php</strong> on line <strong>23</strong>"`

Is there a way I can set the table name with todays date in it? I feel like there must be an easy way to do this that I have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use expressions while creating a field value, but you can override it inside the model constructor:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->table = "probe_request_" . Carbon::now('Europe/London')->startOfDay()->format('d_m_Y');
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the new table name like this.

```
$ProbeRequest= new ProbeRequest;
$ProbeRequest->setTable("probe_request_" . $this->getDate);
```